# Java Swing how to create a task reminder

Tags: java, api, alarm

How to create a event reminder. Example, an user created an event which is today 5.00pm and stored it into database. When ruun the program the reminder will pop up if the system time is 5.00pm. Is there any API can do that? From google what I got was those freeware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you use Date to represent the time you want to fire the alert, schedule a custom Callable task in a ScheduledExecutorService.

Ths code would look like this:

```
myScheculer.schedule(alertTime.getTime() - System.currentTimeMillis(), new AlertTask());
```

In the AlertTask implementation, use JOptionPane.showMessage() to pop the notification.

Comment: Hi can use TimerTask to do so?

Comment: Yes you can if you prefer. No big difference. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409932 and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/637110